# new class or multiple methods for processing speed

Tags: java, oop

NOTE: I am not very well versed in programming, this is my first time posting on stackoverflow, and need guidance.

I am working on a pre-made program (coded by someone else) and have been asked to make one of the process quicker. The program stores all its data in a database.

The process: 
So the process takes in 2 parameters, example username and password. It then searches its 'user' table and returns the data in the row linked to this user.This uses an sql command. As the user object is made up of a few basic fields (String, int) and some other custom classes, it is required to call another method to return the related objects, which uses another sql call. 
In total there are 4 sql calls. (1 to create the 'user' object, and another 3 to create the 3 custom objects that the 'user' object needs.

What i would like to do is create a new class (a temp class), which holds all the required data, and use this class to created the the small classes that help make up the 'user' class. Which will reduce the 4 sql calls to 1 sql call.

my question would be, **Would this be a better way of improving the processing time?** I'm afraid if i used this method it increases 'coupling' and it isn't a good programming move.

Comment: Off the top of my head: Why not join the user table to the other metadata tables in your database and then just return a single result set?  You don't necessarily need to create wrapper classes to encapsulate a database record.  Rather, you could just use an object array `Object[]` to represent each record.

Comment: less sql call == less io == less execution time

Comment: @glee8e - usually && sometimes && sometimes not

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am not allowed to adjust the database. As all of them are different type of objects, i cant put them in the same array can i?

Comment: @ScaryWombat well... after all only profiling can prove if an optimization is beneficial.

Comment: You can put them in an Object[] but that would become messy if there are many fields.  You'd be better off creating an object where each field in the table is an attribute.

Comment: @glee8e That i know, but from my knowledge, to create an object with data from the table, i will have to call one sql for each object (current no. of objects = 4) Is there a way to create 4 different objects with a single sql call?

Comment: with PreparedStatement you can do joins

Comment: @JacobG. That was what i was thinking of doing. but would it be 'a bad programming move' as i am increasing coupling?

Comment: @AlyxEsson - You can't have it both ways (all of the time).  Improving performance is probably going to increase coupling, in some sense.  You need to decide which is more important to you.

Comment: You don't need to "adjust" the database.  Most likely, you can knock this off with a single query.

Comment: Reducing the number of SQL calls is (generally) a big win. How you structure your classes is (again, generally) far less important.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen as in joining the tables in the sql 'select' call? but i will need a model class (i have just read about this name) to hold these data.